# We NEED ZEND .zfproject.xml for SOCIAL ENGINE Netbeans Developers

Tags: zend-framework, netbeans, socialengine, netbeans-7.4

Most of the **Social Engine Developers use Netbeans**. Netbeans doesn't treat any project as ZEND without the file **.zfproject.xml**. hence Netbeans doesn't provide important tools like **ZEND command GUI tool**.(even if it provides, it won't work).zfproject.xml is used by **Zend_Tool** to store information about created controllers, actions, etc. within project How can I have a .zfproject.xml file for NETBEANS which reflect the directory, file etc structures of social engine.

I found dat .zfproject.xml requires the following files to recognize any zend project. Where are these files in **SOCIAL ENGINE context.-**

- /configs/aplication.ini (configuration file)
- /controllers (controllerdirectory)
- /bootstrap.php (the first bootstrap file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanx for the reply. Yes I have already realized what u said but still we cant get the directory structure in socialengine to work as core zend application.The link u posted is all about setting netbeans for zend,which I did easily, but not for SOCIALENGINE.The .zfproject.xml created by Zend Tool is all about this.By default it maintains everything about zend, not socialengine.It also requires an application.ini, which socialengine doesnt have.Zend also starts from application/modules, whereas social engines starts from application/modules/mymodules.Only if we could reflect these changes into .zfproject.xml to match socialengine, that wud be it.

Answer (score 0):

1. SE4 doesnt have application.ini, just several php files in application/settings/
2. controllers placed inside modules folder (e.g. application/modules/Core/controllers)
3. application/modules/Core/Bootstrap.php

Try this manual, hope it help: [Setup Netbeans for Zend Framework Development](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/292856/Setup-Netbeans-for-Zend-Framework-Development)